Search Datasheet IT8786E-I/HX
Can you help me find the datasheet of IT8786E-I/HX ?

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/hwmon/it87 with a special mention ...
IT8786E
Prefix: 'it8786'
Addresses scanned: from Super I/O config space (8 I/O ports)
Datasheet: Not publicly available

On a quick search found:

https://github.com/huchanghui123/ITE-SuperIO/blob/master/IT8786E-I_B_V0.2.pdf is someone uploading the datasheet to github, which is Preliminary Specification V0.2 (For B Version).
https://www.ite.com.tw/uploads/product_download/IT8783_A_V0.5_062510.pdf, which is Preliminary Specification V0.5 (For A Version). Interestingly, while is is watermarked as "confidential" it is uploaded to the ITE website and google found it.

Given these are Preliminary Specifications, not sure how many details of the registers differ from a revision of an IT8786E-I/HX device used in a PC.
As noted in a comment on the question from @Antonio51 suspect the datasheets for the devices were not intended to be publicly available.
Also found https://review.coreboot.org/c/coreboot/+/30335 which is when support for IT8786E-I was added to the coreboot software. That might be useful to understand the registers. Commit comment was:

superio/ite: Add IT8786E-I
Based on IT8786E-I V0.4.1 datasheet with following remark:
"Please note that the IT8786E-I V0.4.1 is
applicable only to the D version."


Good job, thank you !! @Chester Gillon
